# Is surrounding environment a redundancy?

Tags: word-usage

In my language ‘mediu inconjurator’ would be literally translated as [‘surrounding environment’](http://www.lighting.co.uk/news/mit-creates-led-that-cools-its-surrounding-environment/8627537.article). Even though this term is widely used it is well known as a redundancy.

I wonder whether this case is similar in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a tautology (which is the more precise English word for what you describe here as "redundancy"), because "environment" by itself doesn't necessarily imply proximity. A better literal translation might be "surrounding environs", which *would* be a tautology. But it's not a widely used phrase.

Comment: Thank you. What if I’d translated the phrase as ‘surrounding medium’?

Comment: A medium is not quite the same thing as an environment. In this context, it would be an environment that provides nutrition to organisms living in it, like a culture medium for bacteria.